# NavLink in react-router-dom not clearing the previously loaded component data.

Tags: reactjs, redux

My index.js file look like this.

```
<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header title={"IBP"}/>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/observation/list" component={App} />
        </div>

        <Footer />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>   </Provider>

<Header /> contain nav data.

<Footer /> contain footer data
```

Header contain link for navigation it look something like this

```
<li className="dropdown">
          <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Observation <span className="caret"></span></a>
          <ul className="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><NavLink to="/Observation/list">Observations</NavLink></li>
            <li><a href="#">Checklists</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Datasets</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

HomePage component and App component have data to show in between Header component and Footer Component.

Now the Question is:

If i navigate  between "/" and "/observation/list" the store data for component not clearing out. 
I want that once  i am on "/observation/list" and from here goes to "/" through NavLink in header component, all the data must clear out of App component.

Anonymous Behaviour:

If i replace NavLink with Href in Header component Everthing Working Fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the above problem by using componentWillunmount method, which going to clear your state once the give componet unMount.

```
>  componentWillUnmount(){
>        
>        //clear the page
> 
>       }
```

Those who are using redux as state manager, they need to create the action creater, that going to set the state value to default value in reducers.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to accomplish that is by using the Life-cycle event [componentDidMount()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html). Since this event is triggered every time the component is mount, you can create a method to clear your state (data) and call it inside componentDidMount().

```
componentDidMount(){
  //Clear your data
}
```